# kAudioFileStreamError_DiscontinuityCantRecover in AudioFileStreamParseBytes

Tags: ios, audio-streaming

I'm trying to make an audio streaming app. 
I open stream, AudioFileStreamOpen (all ok) but when I try to parse I get kAudioFileStreamError_DiscontinuityCantRecover. Apple doc is not clear.

```
err = AudioFileStreamOpen(self, MyPropertyListenerProc, MyPacketsProc,
                          fileTypeHint, &audioFileStream);

... // other things

AudioFileTypeID fileTypeHint = kAudioFileWAVEType;
err = AudioFileStreamParseBytes(audioFileStream, length, bytes,
                                kAudioFileStreamParseFlag_Discontinuity);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused because the audio straming file could not set as kAudioFileStreamParseFlag_Discontinuity the simple solution was:

```
   err = AudioFileStreamParseBytes(audioFileStream, length, bytes,
                            0);
```